# What is the appropriate way to close a python requests.session?

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I have a nodejs server uses session to store user login info and the auth will immediately invalidated after session closed. The actual behavior is when I close my browser and reopen the web, I am required to login again to gain access.

Now I am trying to use python requests package, setup requests.Session with login info to maintain an alive connection for several post requests, and close the session so further connections will not be allowed. I was thinking `requests.Session.close()` is the way to do that, but found that it will not close the "session" as the browser did. Although the documentation indicates that "Closes all adapters and as such the session".

I guess I totally misunderstand the purpose of this function, so may I ask what is the appropriate way to close the session so further connections from the session doesn't have the auth info?

Below is the sample code I am using.

```
import requests
s=requests.Session()
url_login = 'http://localhost:8080/login'
url_postStatus = 'http://localhost:8080/postStatus'
loginInfo={'UserEmail':'test@test.test','UserPassword':'test'}
s.post(url_login,data=loginInfo)
s.post(url_postStatus)
s.close()
s.post(url_postStatus)
```

Comment: I feel some misconception here - how browser close the session? What happens then?

Comment: if you don't want to use session then use `requests.post()`.  Evetually you should clear cookies from session to remove auth info. `s.cookies.clear()`